# Does Tarantool have connector for PHP 7?

Tags: php, php-7, tarantool

I'd like to use Tarantool with new PHP 7. I have found a driver here https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool-php, but it is only suitable for PHP 5.

Comment: As I know php 7 driver for tarantool does not exists.
Try to ask about this the developers at GH.

Comment: The GitHub Issues page has an open item reflecting this https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool-php/issues/46 Did you look there first?

Comment: Thanks, Josh J. It's my fault, they are really working on it already.
Anyway, maybe you know some ready thirdparty solutions? As I can see an issue is old enough (opened on 1 Jun 2015 ), so I'm not sure that it will be closed soon.
upd: bigbes has answered already: "PHP7 driver is in development. Alpha version is in public, but it's very fragile."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP7 driver is in development. Alpha version is in public, but it's very fragile.

It's located on `php7-v1` branch of https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool-php repository.

As an alternative, you may also try pure php driver, which also works on php7: https://github.com/tarantool-php/client.

Comment: As an alternative, you may also try [pure php](https://github.com/tarantool-php/client) driver, which also works on php7.

Comment: Thanks, bigbes. I'll try it. And I'm looking forward for not fragile version:)